# Несколько команд в 1 .cmd файле

Tags: cmd

Я добавил команду cods в cmd тк часто использую cmd для перехода в мою директорию python и java.
1(cods.cmd)

```
 @echo off
 D:
 cd D:\cods\
```

2(cods aiogram.cmd)

```
 @echo off
 D:
  cd D:\cods\aiogram
```

3(cods aiogram test.cmd)

```
 @echo off
 D:
 cd D:\cods\aiogram\test
```

И мне нужно чтобы каждая команда работала сама например мне нужно в директорию aiogram и я пишу в cmd cods aiogram и меня перекидывает в D:\cods\aiogram но когда я пишу это он меня кидает в D:\cods типо я написал команду cods

Comment: Честно, мало, что понятно. Вы свои команды (последовательно) в вопрос напишите и оформите как код, чтобы они в одну линию не были

Comment: " я пишу в cmd cods aiogram" - а это намного короче чем в смd набрать cd d:\cods\a [нажимаем Tab] получаем -> cd d:\cods\aiogram жмём [Enter] - всё